# using vuejs, when colspan data increments I want to remove a <td></td>

Tags: vue.js

So I have been fiddling with vuejs a few weeks now. What I am trying to do is if my colspan increments more than what the default value was--I need a  to remove each time. So if my colspan starts out as 3 and the data changes to 4. one  needs to be removed. So in other words, if the span increments by 1, a  should be gone. would I use v-if in all of the below td spans??? guess I would use v-if and v-show and them maybe a method to check to see? any ideas--anyone?

```html
    <div id="growth">
        <tr class="body_top">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="#" colspan="0"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="{{column1Span}}"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <!-- <td></td> -->
            <!-- <td></td> -->
        </tr>

        <tr class="body_top">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="#" colspan="0"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="{{column2Span}}"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td v-if="column2Span"></td>
            <!-- <td></td> -->
            <!-- <td></td> -->
        </tr>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <script>
            new Vue({
                el: '#growth',
                data: {
                    column1Span: '2',
                    column2Span: '3',
                    column3Span: '1',
                    column4Span: '3',
                    column5Span: '1',
                    column6Span: '1'

                },
                methods:{
                    
                }


            })

        </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do what you suggest.  Just add v-if conditions according to the number of td you are away from the one with the colspan defined.  I did the first on as an example:

```js
new Vue({
                el: '#growth',
                data: {
                    column1Span: '3',
                    column2Span: '3',
                    column3Span: '1',
                    column4Span: '3',
                    column5Span: '1',
                    column6Span: '1'

                },
                methods:{
                    
                }

            })
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="growth">
  <table>
        <tr class="body_top">
            <td>1</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="#" colspan="0"></td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td colspan="{{column1Span}}">4</td>
            <td v-if="column1Span < 3">5</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <!-- <td></td> -->
            <!-- <td></td> -->
        </tr>

        <tr class="body_top">
            <td>7</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="#" colspan="0"></td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td colspan="{{column2Span}}">10</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td v-if="column2Span"></td>
            <!-- <td></td> -->
            <!-- <td></td> -->
        </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```